# Как можно изменить эту часть кода? Ошибка вызвана тем что я пытаюсь использовать ее в C# 4 а она как я понял из C#6

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно изменить эту часть кода? Ошибка вызвана тем что я пытаюсь использовать ее в C# 4 а она как я понял из C# 6.0

Сама ошибка:

> Assets/Game/Lang/LocalizationManager.cs(22,35): error CS1644: Feature
>   `auto-implemented property initializer' cannot be used because it is
>   not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

```
//вот тут ошибка
public static EnLanguageEvent ChangeLanguage { get; set; } = new EnLanguageEvent();
```

Она вызывается тут

```
private void SelectLanguage(EnLanguage _language)
    {
        laguage = _language;
        ChangeLanguage.Invoke(laguage);
    }
```

Comment: Инициализируйте в конструкторе или где там в юнити у вас стартовая точка скрипта. `= new EnLanguageEvent();` уберите и в конструкторе `ChangeLanguage = new EnLanguageEvent();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно исправить несколькими способами

1. Как подсказали в комментарии, уберите инициализацию в момент объявления самого property и в конструкторе класса (если не `MonoBehaviour` наследник), или, например в методах `Awake()`, `Start()` (для `MonoBehaviour` наследников) добавьте `hangeLanguage = new EnLanguageEvent();`
2. Создать приватную переменную, на которую и будет ссылаться property, заменив auto-property обычным

   ```
   private static EnLanguageEvent _changeLanguage = new EnLanguageEvent();
   public static EnLanguageEvent ChangeLanguage 
   {
         get { return _changeLanguage; } 
         set { _changeLanguage = value; } 
   }
   ```